# Check state of combobox and change textbox readonly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a form that displays a datagridview and a textbox and combobox. When a column name is selected in the combobox, and a search typed in the textbox it filters and displays the searched data.
How can I detect if the combobox has nothing selected, and change the textbox readonly state to true, and when something is selected, change it back to false so I can search?

```
DataTable dt;
        private void searchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf;");
            SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from customersTBL", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            comboSearch.Items.Add("[First Name]");
                comboSearch.Items.Add("Surename");
            comboSearch.Items.Add("[Address Line 1]");
            comboSearch.Items.Add("[Address Line 2]");
            comboSearch.Items.Add("County");
            comboSearch.Items.Add("[Post Code]");
            comboSearch.Items.Add("[Contact Number]");
            comboSearch.Items.Add("[Email Address]");



        }



        private void searchTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = "" + comboSearch.Text.Trim() + "like '%" + searchTxt.Text.Trim() + "%'";
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty item to the combobox and then

```
if(comboSearch.SelectedItem =="")
{
searchTxt.ReadOnly = true;
}
else
{
searchTxt.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

After executing your code add this line:

```
comboSearch.SelectedIndex =0;
```

Make sure your empty item is the first item.

Comment: then you need to have an empty item in the list box, i'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if( ComboBox.SelectedItem == null ) {
   // do something
TextBox.ReadOnly = true;       //Using the TextBox.ReadOnly property

}
else{
Textbox.ReadOnly=false;
}
```

hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a row in your FormLoad to the comboSearch control for a blank line. Make sure it's about the [First Name] item.

```
comboSearch.Items.Add(string.Empty);
comboSearch.Items.Add("[First Name]");
```

Add an event handler to comboSearch for SelectedIndexChanged. Inside the event, set the searchTxt control's ReadOnly property. It may look like this:

```
private void comboSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchTxt.ReadOnly = comboSearch.SelectedIndex != 0;
}
```

Comment: The textbox doesn't change read only state, it just stays readonly = false

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the searchTxt.ReadOnly line to verify that your program is executing that line. Also while debugging that line verify what the SelectedIndex is when you click the top (blank) row. Be sure you tied the event to the comboSearch box in the Properties window in design view.

Answer (score 0):

I added a SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
private void comboSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchTxt.ReadOnly = false;
        }
```

And changed the TextChanged event to:

```
private void searchTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboSearch.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                searchTxt.ReadOnly = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a search criteria");
            }



            else
            {
                searchTxt.ReadOnly = false;
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = "" + comboSearch.Text.Trim() + "like '%" + searchTxt.Text.Trim() + "%'";
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
            }
        }
```

and it now functions how I'd like it to

Comment: But a user could begin typing when a search criteria isn't already selected? Why not prevent the user from typing at all when there is not search criteria selected? Just my opinion, glad you figured it out.

Comment: I tried all the other answers and none would work, this works for me.